# Crear varios objetos con una misma interfaz, pero con propiedades diferentes

Tags: c#, .net

Tengo una interfaz

```
public interface IComprobante
{
     int Numero { get; set; }
     short NumCompania { get; set; }
     short PuntoDeVenta { get; set; }
}
```

Y tengo 3 clases que heredan de ella:

```
public class Factura : IComprobante
{
     public int Numero { get; set; }
     public short NumCompania { get; set; }
     public short PuntoDeVenta { get; set; }
}

public class NotaDeCredito : IComprobante
{
        
     public List<Factura> Facturas { get; set; }

     public int Numero { get; set; }
     public short NumCompania { get; set; }
     public short PuntoDeVenta { get; set; }
}

public class NotaDeDebito : IComprobante
{
     public List<Factura> Facturas { get; set; }

     public int Numero { get; set; }
     public short NumCompania { get; set; }
     public short PuntoDeVenta { get; set; }
}
```

Como pueden observar, NotaDeCredito y NotaDeDebito tienen un propiedad extra llamada "List Facturas" ¿como hago para crear un objeto de IComprobante? en donde, si creo:
IComprobante notaDeDebito = new NotaDeDebito();
Pueda acceder a la propiedad notaDeDebito.Facturas.

Creando desde la interfaz y no desde el objeto en si.

Comment: Tienes un pequeño error de concepto: Cuando dices `Creando desde la interfaz y no desde el objeto en si.` Una interfaz no puede ser instanciada, simplemente sirve como un contrato que dice qué métodos debe implementar una clase que justamente implementa dicha interfaz. A su vez, cuando dices `Y tengo 3 clases que heredan de ella:` tus clases no están "heredando" de la interfaz, si no que están implementando la interfaz.

Comment: Cuando declaras la variable `IComprobante notaDeDebito = new NotaDeDebito();` el compilador entiende que `notaDeDebito` es de tipo `IComprobante`, por lo tanto no sabe de ninguna propiedad adicional que tengan tus clases que la implementan. Solo sabe de las que tiene la interfaz `IComprobante`.

Comment: Hola Ale, podrias decir si la respuesta dada te resulto util y en caso de serlo marcarla como aceptada, gracias